# Disable GPU Boost

Tags: winapi, graphics, 3d, directx

I'm programming a game and I want to be able to disable GPU boost in my GTX 680 card from the source code, i.e. with c++ or assembly. I know this question might be a little odd, but I can't think of any other way to word it.

I'm reading a book on dx11 programming (Frank De Lunas), and I am getting really low frame rates in one of the advanced examples. I monitored my gpu speed and it was running at idle speeds (324 Mhz). The problem is probably how the demo was coded, but it may me think that regardless of that I will like to have the ability of turning GPU boost off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best hope is to use [NVAPI](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi) for something like this, however, [this thread](https://forums.nvidia.com/default/topic/519233/how-can-i-disable-gpu-boost-gtx-670/) on the nVidia forums makes it pretty clear that its nigh impossible to disable (at least is a safe, nVidia approved manner).

Comment: Thanks brother, I had no idea such an api existed.